# Why My Unity 2D Platformer Game's Android Button Controller doesn't working correctly?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, button, controller

So here I am a game developer who recently used unity and have almost given up on dealing with this stuff.

I'm currently working on a 2d platformer game.
And one that is left behind, the android control button.

I use "standard assets",
Unity's "CrossPlatformInput" to create the android controller I need.

And after being tested, it doesn't work at all to move the characters in the game.
I have followed the guide carefully and carefully many times, but the result is still the same

Can anyone help tell what happened?

this is the failing code i am using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class Pemain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float movespeed = 5f;
    public int jumppower;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool onGround;
    private Animator anim;
    private int facing; 

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        jumppower = 5;
        facing = 1;
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position,groundCheckRadius,whatIsGround);
    }

    void Update () {

        float move = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2 (-movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
            anim.SetBool ("Walking", true);
            if (facing == 1)
            {
                transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1f, 1f, 1f);
                facing = 0;
            }
        } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
            anim.SetBool ("Walking", true);
            if (facing == 0)
            {
                transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1f, 1f, 1f);
                facing = 1;
            }
        } else
        {
            anim.SetBool ("Walking", false);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && onGround)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2 (rb.velocity.x,jumppower);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the `move` variable at all in your code. So the CrossPlatformInput can't take any influence on the movement of your character. You should change the code to something similar to this.

```
float move = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");

if (move < -0.01f)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (-movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
        anim.SetBool ("Walking", true);
        if (facing == 1)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1f, 1f, 1f);
            facing = 0;
        }
    } else if (move > 0.01f)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
        anim.SetBool ("Walking", true);
        if (facing == 0)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1f, 1f, 1f);
            facing = 1;
        }
    }
```

You might also want to brush up on your C# skills, as learning Unity **and** programming at the same time is very difficult.